# Rails asset pipeline fingerprinting and page caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I'm using rails page caching (with memcache) on one page of my website. The cache has an expiration time of 24 hours. But the cache value contains some assets named asset-FINGERPRINT.css

If I run a deploy during the 24 hours of cache existence, the fingerprint changes but I still have the old version in my cache value. So I get 404s when I try to fetch the assets.

I have multiple versions of the page so I can't manually expire the page after each deploy. My question is, has anyone encountered the same problem and what was the solution?

Comment: IMHO in this situation you should reset cache

Comment: I'm afraid that the load of the server will reach the roof if i reset the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I wouldn't be deleting the old versions of assets. In addition to the problem you are facing, you probably don't want the old version of the HTML being used alongside new CSS or Javascript - that could easily break things if you aren't careful.

Because each version of the assets has a fingerprint you can have the current and several previous versions available concurrently. One way of doing this is by symlinking public/assets to a folder that doesn't change between releases (If you deploy using capistrano this happens for you if you use the default asset pipeline integration).

All that said, being in a situation where you feel you can't ever clear the cache feels precarious to me.

Comment: It's a good idea! And yes it is precarious, but it's temporary ;-)